# Can we prove that, there exist infinitely many $k$, such that $m^k-k\equiv 0\pmod n ?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $m,n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}$ are fixed numbers, such that $$m^{k_0}-k_0\equiv 0\pmod n$$ for some $k_0\in \Bbb N$.
> Then, there exist infinitely many $k$, such that $$m^k-k\equiv 0\pmod n.$$

**The Question:** Is this conjecture always true?

My attempt is numerical.

Let $m=3, n=7,k=2$ we have $$3^2-2\equiv 0\pmod 7$$

I found that:

$$k\in\ [4,5,27,31,36...]$$

Then I took $m=2,n=5, k=3$, then $2^3-3\equiv 0\pmod 5$. I found the following values:

$$k\in[14,16,17,23,34...]$$ and so on.

This seems correct to me as if it were the result of a some theorem/conjecture. But I couldn't find the result of which theorem or conjecture.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140502/discussion-on-question-by-user-can-we-prove-that-there-exist-infinitely-many-k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated in the comments, the conjecture as written is true. Since both sequences

$$a_k=\{1,2,...\}$$

$$b_k=\{m^1,m^2,...\}$$

are periodic modulo $n$, we may conclude that $b_k-a_k$ has period at most $\text{Period}(a_k)\text{Period}(b_k)$. Since at least one member of $b_k-a_k$ is congruent to $0$, an infinite number of sequence members are congruent to $0$.

A natural extension to this question: for what $(m,n)$ does such an initial solution even exist? I'm not sure how to answer this but I'll edit this if I'm able to prove anything useful.

EDIT 1: I checked, and I can't find any counterexamples up to $n=656$. Given the number-theoretic/multiplicative nature of this question I take this as strong evidence that such an initial solution will always exist.

Comment: $b_k$ has a period of $\varphi(n)$ (totient function) doesn't it?  As far as the last sentence, if $n$ is a prime power then $\varphi(n)$ is coprime to $n$.  So for $n=p\varphi + q$ then $m^k \equiv k$ gives $\frac{p = q - m^q}{\varphi}$ so a solution always exists.  A program I wrote can't find any counter examples in any other case either.

Comment: At least $\phi(n)$ is a multiple of the minimum period. For the extended question that might be enough. Honestly I can't seem to find any counterexamples either. If someone could post one that would be pretty helpful in determining what (if any) is the important behavior

Comment: @DanielV Not necessarily. The period will divide $\varphi(n)$ though.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Agree, a period but not necessarily the minimum period.  I meant to write (type) $$p \equiv \frac{q - m^q}{\varphi}$$ before, apologies.

Comment: @User It is a bit dismissive to ask for a solution to a harder question when he both answered the question you asked, and said he would provide the answer to the harder question if he could anyway.  I would suggest instead just saying thanks.  And usually I would suggest posting another question if you want the harder question answered, but do you really know modular arithmetic?  Would you understand the solution if someone gave it to you?

Comment: @DanielV +1 already means, thank you very much.  You  missed my point, I think. I will ask another one , but please see above comments. My question comes from above comments (under the my question). Because, after some discussion I thought: Is my conjecture contains trivially "a lot of work"? Because,   now I observed, actually we don't need $k_0$. That's why I asked. Do we 
really need $k_0$?

Comment: Only wrong in my comment: Can *we* prove that we don't need $k_0$? That was a what I mean exactly.

Comment: @QC_QAOA Do you also think $k_0$ is unnecessary?

Comment: I do, just based on my tests as well as intuition, it seems reasonable to conjecture that every $(m,n)$ will have some solution $k$. Proving that is difficult however

Comment: @QC_QAOA Thank you. What I mean: If this is not trivial, I want will ask as another question. Because, the trivial questions are not welcome in the site. Also: You already answer the original question. I think, you shouldn't change your answer. Because it is okay, as it seems.

Comment: @User I think asking another question is a good idea, just link back to this question when providing motivation (can also use my result up to $n=60$)